# range loop exiting out early when assigning array of header names?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a TON of headers that I need to assign to a worksheet, but I'm doing it with just a select few to test out. What I am trying to do is assign 4 cells in a range, and also assign 4 text values for each concurrent cell in that predefined range.

```
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range("E3,O3,AF3:AG3")
Dim header() As Variant: header() = Array("Department Name", "Hire Date (Most Recent)", "Region", "District")

For Each cell In rng
    Cell.Value = header(i)
Next cell
```

it works well for the first one `Department Name`, but then it exits out of the loop in the next go-around and moves on to the rest of the code, any clue how I can alter it to cycle through and label appropriately?

rest of code (partial):

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Corporate", "OtherCorporate", "DC", "Stores", "Hires"
            With ws
                Dim i As Long, cell As Range, rng As Range
                Dim header() As Variant: header() = Array("Department Name", "Hire Date (Most Recent)", "Region", "District")
                .Range("L:M, R:T, AC:AG, AJ:AK, AR:BF").EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
                .Range("I:I, M:N, AN:AO").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Set rng = Range("E3,O3,AF3:AG3")
                    For Each cell In rng
                        i = 1
                        cell.Value = header(i)
                        i = i + 1
                    Next cell
            End With
```

Comment: What is `i`?... you never assign it a value.

Comment: Also note that while you're using a `With` statement, you're not preceding your `Range`s with a period, so they're still working off your `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Also note that you delete column `AG` after you've `Set rng = Range("E3,O3,AF3:AG3")`.... that might cause you issues.

Comment: @BigBen `i` is supposed to be the counter in my `header` array. How would I assign a value? I thought that was done by putting it inside of the `()`

Comment: Assignment would look like `i = ....`

Comment: @BigBen good catch on the set, and I think I know what I need to do, but would I place that before or in between my for each loop?

Comment: Move the `Set` to *after* the line that deletes.

Comment: @BigBen is that what you're referring to? Updated my post in the Rest of Code: section

Comment: You've fixed the `Set`. Get rid of the `For i = 1` loop. Add `i = i + 1` after `cell.Value = header(i)`. Maybe add `i = 0` outside the `For Each` loop.

Comment: @BigBen would I just put i = 1 in the for each loop, and then i +1 before the next cell part?

Comment: Get rid of the `i=1` and add `i=0` before the loop. The array is zero-based.

Comment: `Set rng = .Range("E3,O3,AF3:AG3")` - note the period.

Comment: @bigben thanks, and I added the i = i+1 in the for loop and its working now! Thanks a lot

Comment: If you don't change the `i=1` to `i=0`, your code will skip the first item in your array. Because, as @BigBen commented, an array is `zero` based, The count of the items in your array start from zero, e.g. If you have 5 items, the count would be `0 to 4`. If you want to you can use `Option Base 1` at the beginning of your code to change the default to 1 instead of 0